# Create new columns based on mathematical calculation

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df

X24_TT_1.1  X135_121.FTT_2.1    X1055_121.FTT_3.1
   0.14          0.84                 0.92
   0.88          0.06                 0.08
   0.91          0.17                 0.85
   0.08          0.9                  0.11
   0.11          0.16                 0.04
   0.83          0.1                  0.87
```

I want to create new columns which has same name with additional "_P" added at last and calculation formula is :

for column  X24_TT_1.1 = 24 * (0.14/(1-0.14))

for column  X135_121.FTT_2.1 = 135 * (0.84/(1-0.84))

for column  X1055_121.FTT_3.1 = 1055 * (0.92/(1-0.92))

And finally it should look like this:

```
X24_TT_1.1  X135_121.FTT_2.1    X1055_121.FTT_3.1   X24_TT_1.2_P    X135_121.FTT_2.2_P  X1055_121.FTT_3.2_P
0.14              0.84               0.92              3.91            708.75             12132.50
0.88              0.06               0.08            176.00              8.62             91.74
0.91              0.17               0.85            242.67             27.65             5978.33
0.08              0.9                0.11              2.09           1215.00             130.39
0.11              0.16               0.04              2.97             25.71              43.96
0.83              0.1                0.87            117.18             15.00            7060.38
```

I want to do this dynamically as dataset has more than 100 columns

Comment: I want to do this dynamically as dataset has more than 100 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- sapply(names(df), function(x) {
            s <- strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][1]
            s <- substring(s, 2, nchar(s))
            as.numeric(s)*(df[,x]/(1 - df[,x]))
     })


colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(df), "_P")
cbind(df, round(x,2))

  X24_TT_1.1 X135_121.FTT_2.1 X1055_121.FTT_3.1 X24_TT_1.1_P X135_121.FTT_2.1_P X1055_121.FTT_3.1_P
1       0.14             0.84              0.92         3.91             708.75            12132.50
2       0.88             0.06              0.08       176.00               8.62               91.74
3       0.91             0.17              0.85       242.67              27.65             5978.33
4       0.08             0.90              0.11         2.09            1215.00              130.39
5       0.11             0.16              0.04         2.97              25.71               43.96
6       0.83             0.10              0.87       117.18              15.00             7060.38
```

Comment: I want to do this dynamically as dataset has more than 100 columns

Comment: @ROY see my update

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $ sign to add a new column to your data frame, doing the following:

```
df$X24_TT_1.1_P <- 24 * (df$X24_TT_1.1/(1-df$X24_TT_1.1))
```

EDIT

Assuming that you have the numbers who are going to multiply each column in a separate list, you could do this dinamically:

```
multiplier <- c(24,135,1055)
A = c(2, 3, 5) 
B = c(4, 5, 6) 
C = c(7, 8, 9) 
df = data.frame(A, B, C) 

new_names <- paste(colnames(df), "_P")
names <- c(colnames(df),new_names)
initial_ncol <- ncol(df)
for (i in 1:initial_ncol){

df$name <- multiplier[i] * (df$A/(1-df$A))
colnames(df) <- names[1:(i+initial_ncol)]
}
```

Comment: I want to do this dynamically as dataset has more than 100 columns

Comment: @Roy I have updated